# REST: how to pass dependent resources when creating a new resource?

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

I'm currently figuring out a way how to build our REST webservice so resources can be linked to other resources at creation time. Take the following scenario.

We have `/user/123/` who sits in the collection `/company/456/users/` and also in the global users collection at `/user/123/`

When I want to add a new user to company 456 I perform a `POST` to `/company/456/users/` to add it to this collection. But what if the user resource depends on more than only the company? Lets say for example that the user resource also tracks address information on the user so it might also depend on the `/country/12/` resource. How can I pass the dependency on the country to the REST webservice. Should I just pass a country_id in the payload of the POST request?

What is considered best-practice for the RESTful approach to managing links to other resources?

Answer (score 1):

Ummm... posting to `/company/456/users/` does not look right to me...
What about posting to `/users`, or even better to `/user/{newid}`?

From there, you can either just create a user, and maybe add links in another moment, or you can specify all the links as url-encoded parameters (or in the payload, but I prefer the former... it just looks cleaner to me, but this is only my personal opinion):

`POST /users?company_id=456&county_id=12`
or
`POST /users?company_id=456`
or
`POST /users`